# Apache tomcat Cluster using mod_proxy gives nonserizable exception for a JSF application

Tags: jsf, tomcat, cluster-computing, mod-proxy

I have successfully configure cluster using mod_proxy for a sample application but when I used this cluster for a JSF application I got non serilizable exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setAttribute: Non-serializable attribute ErrorDisplay
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.setAttribute(StandardSession.java:1351)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaSession.setAttribute(DeltaSession.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaSession.setAttribute(DeltaSession.java:631)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.putValue(StandardSessionFacade.java:135)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.ApplicationRequestFilter.activityLoggingAspect(ApplicationRequestFilter.java:365)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.ApplicationRequestFilter.sessionDataAspect(ApplicationRequestFilter.java:317)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.ApplicationRequestFilter.transactionAspect(ApplicationRequestFilter.java:272)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.ApplicationRequestFilter.validURLForUser(ApplicationRequestFilter.java:244)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.ApplicationRequestFilter.authenticationAspect(ApplicationRequestFilter.java:217)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.ApplicationRequestFilter.licenseAuthentication(ApplicationRequestFilter.java:131)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.ApplicationRequestFilter.doFilter(ApplicationRequestFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.DataReloadFilter.doFilter(DataReloadFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.ApplicationRequestFilter.activityLoggingAspect(ApplicationRequestFilter.java:341)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.ApplicationRequestFilter.sessionDataAspect(ApplicationRequestFilter.java:317)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.ApplicationRequestFilter.transactionAspect(ApplicationRequestFilter.java:272)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.ApplicationRequestFilter.validURLForUser(ApplicationRequestFilter.java:244)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.ApplicationRequestFilter.authenticationAspect(ApplicationRequestFilter.java:217)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.ApplicationRequestFilter.licenseAuthentication(ApplicationRequestFilter.java:131)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.ApplicationRequestFilter.doFilter(ApplicationRequestFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve.invoke(JvmRouteBinderValve.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(ReplicationValve.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Is there any restriction using Cluster for a JSF Application ? as exception points out some non serilizable classes how can I make it serializable.

```
 May 2, 2012 1:31:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setAttribute: Non-serializable attribute ErrorDisplay
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.setAttribute(StandardSession.java:1351)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaSession.setAttribute(DeltaSession.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaSession.setAttribute(DeltaSession.java:631)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.putValue(StandardSessionFacade.java:135)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.ApplicationRequestFilter.activityLoggingAspect(ApplicationRequestFilter.java:365)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.ApplicationRequestFilter.sessionDataAspect(ApplicationRequestFilter.java:317)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.ApplicationRequestFilter.transactionAspect(ApplicationRequestFilter.java:272)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.ApplicationRequestFilter.validURLForUser(ApplicationRequestFilter.java:244)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.ApplicationRequestFilter.authenticationAspect(ApplicationRequestFilter.java:217)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.ApplicationRequestFilter.licenseAuthentication(ApplicationRequestFilter.java:131)
    at com.avanza.unison.config.ApplicationRequestFilter.doFilter(ApplicationRequestFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve.invoke(JvmRouteBinderValve.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(ReplicationValve.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 0):

Q1. Is there any restriction using Cluster for a JSF Application?

Answer: No.

Q2. As exception points out some non serilizable classes how can I make it serializable.

Answer: Modify the class that implements the ErrorDisplay object to implement Serializable.